# Python + Selenium JS dropdown select

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I'm totally new, I've gone through some of the examples as you can find these here but as straightforward as it looks I can't make it work.

The page I want to pass: www.webauto.de

My code to select a make, a model and click 'search'.

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.webauto.de')
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'quick-search')))
select = Select(browser.find_element_by_id('carsearchmake'))
select.select_by_visible_text('Ford')
sleep(1)
select = Select(browser.find_element_by_id('carsearchmod'))
select.select_by_visible_text('Fiesta')
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="submit"]').click()
sleep(1)
```

Comment: Why the python tag?

Comment: Because it's written in Python.

Comment: ...then why the javascript tag?

Comment: Because it involves meddling with JS rendered page. Or should I drop that tag in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the an attribute = value CSS selector to target the submit button.

```
from selenium import webdriver

d = webdriver.FireFox()
d.get("https://www.webauto.de/")
d.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='carsearchmake']/option[text()='Ford']").click()
d.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='carsearchmod']/option[text()='Fiesta']").click()
d.find_element_by_css_selector("[value=Suchen]").click()
#d.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you were pretty close.

The *xpath*:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="submit"]')
```

doesn't identifies the desired *search* button uniquely and you can use the following solution:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='https://www.webauto.de/site/de/suchen/' and contains(.,'Erweiterte Suche')]//following::a[1]/input").click()
```

Comment: I think my select a make and model from a dropdown menu was stalling so I didn't had the chance to really check this out. The other guy's answer works 100% for me but thank you too for your time and contribution.

Comment: @DrDro Great news. Count yourself lucky. If I am not mistaken, for me neither `find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="submit"]')` nor `find_element_by_css_selector("[value=Suchen]")` identifies the desired button uniquely but **3 (three)** elements. Ofcoarse `//a[@href='https://www.webauto.de/site/de/suchen/' and contains(.,'Erweiterte Suche')]//following::a[1]/input` (_as per my answer_) does.